# Array Filter limit amount of results PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following method

```
public function getNextAvailableHousesToAttack(\DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Collection $collection, $hordeSize)
{
    $houses = $collection->getHouses();

    $housesThatCanBeAttacked = array_filter($houses, function($house) use (&$hordeSize) {
        if(!isset($house)) {
            return false;
        }
        $house = $this->houseModel->applyMaxAttackCapacity($house, $hordeSize);
        if($this->houseModel->isAttackable($house)) {
            return $house;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return $housesThatCanBeAttacked;
```

However, this array can be *huge*.

I want to limit `$housesThatCanBeAttacked` to whatever the size of `$hordeSize` is set to, as I only need as many houses as there are zombies in the horde to attack this round.

However, this array `$housesThatCanBeAttacked` could end up containing 1 million houses, where there are only 100 in the zombie horde.

Is there a way to limit the  size of this array built from the callback?

Comment: Can't you just `array_slice()` to produce a smaller subset?

Comment: I'm relying on my conditional checks within the `array_filter` to determine whether they should be included within the array, suitable houses can - although not always - be spread through the array.

Comment: In the resultant array, what differentiates a house that can be attacked from what they can't? Is there a property or something?

Comment: A house `isAttackable` if the current attackers < max attack capacity. @Utkanos

Comment: Where does your 1m+ House data come from? A database?

Comment: You could wrap your filter is a `try .. catch` block and throw an 'enoughResults' exception when the output array has enough values? I cannot think of another way of terminating the filter early. Yes, it isn't what exceptions are for... ;-/

Comment: A CSV file @BadHorsie

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a loop, and stop processing the array when you have enough houses.

```
$houses = $collection->getHouses();
housesThatCanBeAttacked[];
$i = 0;

foreach ($houses as $house) {
    $house = $this->houseModel->applyMaxAttackCapacity($house, $hordeSize);
    if ($this->houseModel->isAttackable($house)) {
        housesThatCanBeAttacked[] = $house;
        if (++$i == $hordeSize) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a counter of houses outside of callback and use it inside callback to skip all excessive houses. Here is how a solution can look like:

```
public function getNextAvailableHousesToAttack(\DeadStreet\ValueObject\House\Collection $collection, $hordeSize)
{
    $houses = $collection->getHouses();
    $counter = $hordeSize;

    $housesThatCanBeAttacked = array_filter($houses, function($house) use (&$hordeSize, &$counter) {
        if($counter == 0 && !isset($house)) {
            return false;
        }
        $house = $this->houseModel->applyMaxAttackCapacity($house, $hordeSize);
        if($this->houseModel->isAttackable($house)) {
            $counter--;
            return $house;
        }
        return false;
    });

    return $housesThatCanBeAttacked;
```

This way you `array_filter` won't return more then `$counter` values.

Comment: The problem with this is that it still runs the array_filter callback on all $houses, even once the counter has got to zero. If $houses is very large, it would be better that the processing stops completely once the counter has reached zero.